# Is it possible to set start date and end date with JTAppleCalendar in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift

I want to show a calendar that starts from a specific date.

Please refer to below examples.(start date = 15, end date = 14)

Jan: 1.15~2.14

Feb: 2.15~3.14

Mar: 3.15~4.14

...

I've searched the Internet but I couldn't find solutions.
Is it possible to set start date and end date with JTAppleCalendar in Swift?

Answer (score 0):

It seems like it's impossible to set months start and end date in `JTAppleCalendar` in Swift. So.. I made my calendar by using `UICollectionView`.